# What does "which" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

This sentence is from a [transcript](http://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode.cfm?id=climate-change-increases-cattle-bre-11-06-15#comments) of a podcast:

> The researchers say that even mammals that breed year round—which should offer protection against seasonal shifts—may still feel the impact of climate change.

I don't understand what the word "which" means here. Does it refer to the "mammals"? If it does, I am confused by the whole sentence — what's the connection between the middle part of the sentence and the rest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *which* in this sentence refers to breeding year round, not the mammals per se. In other words:

> Breeding year round should protect mammals from seasonal shifts.  However, despite this protection, these mammals may still feel the impact of climate change.

Answer (score 5):

It refers to **[the fact] that they breed year round**. The word *which* can be used to refer to an entire sentence, to a specific noun phrase, to any other part of a sentence, or even to a concept that isn't explicitly mentioned. Several other pronouns can do the same:

> Christians refused to worship the Emperor. *That* was not to the liking of the Roman government.

Here *that* refers to the entire previous sentence.

Answer (score -1):

It's not grammatically correct, although since it's from a verbal transcript I'm inclined to cut the speaker some slack. (I believe this is an example of a [dangling modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier).)

"Which" refers back to the year-round breeding cycle of said mammals. It might be clearer if we move the object *mammals* to the other side of the parenthetical phrase:

> The researchers say that even breeding year round—which should offer protection against seasonal shifts—may not protect mammals from the impact of climate change.

Comment: I think that as a verbal parenthetical remark, it's fine, but that in an essay, it would have been better written and more readable without the parenthetical remark.

Comment: It is indeed grammatically correct. It is formally ambiguous (though probably not so in practice).